# Caesar Shift Cypher: read text from stdin and shift n characters

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to write a Caesar shift cypher. Quoting Simon Singh:

> The Caesar shift cipher replaces every letter with the letter that is
> a fixed number of places further down the alphabet. For example if the
> shift is 2, then A is replaced with C, B with D, C with E and so on.
> Or if there is a shift of 5 then A is replaced with F, B with G, C
> with H and so on.

I'm trying to read the text from `stdin` and read the number of places for the shift from the first argument which is passed to the script `*argv[1]`. In order to do so, I cast `*argv[1]` to `int` and decrease 48 (ASCII for 0).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char buffer[100];
        char shifted_buffer[100];
        size_t nbytes;
        ssize_t bytes_read;
        int fd;
        fd = fileno(stdin);
        nbytes = sizeof(buffer);
        bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, nbytes);
        int i, n;
        n = *argv[1] - 48;
        for(i=1; i<bytes_read; i++) {
                shifted_buffer[i] = buffer[i]+n;
                }
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", shifted_buffer);
}
```

The behavior I'm expecting is something like:

```
echo -n 'abc' | ./Caesar 1
bcd

echo -n 'abc' | ./Caesar 2
cde
```

And so on.
Unfortunately, what I get is:

```
echo -n 'abc' | ./Caesar 1
?cd??
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You can't get the integer `10` from the string `"10"` by examining the first character. Use the library function `strtol()`. Anyway, don't use magic numbers. To be portable, you should convert the character representation of a digit by subtracting `'0'`, not `48`.

Comment: You are ignoring the first character at index `[0]`, and failing to check that the character is in the desired range: you've read the newline too. And you are failing to consider "wrap": what if the character is `'z'`? Also, don't use `read()` for text, use `fgets()` which will read from `stdin` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you @Weather Vane for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I incorporated all suggestions from [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char buffer[100];
        char shifted_buffer[100];
        size_t nbytes;
        ssize_t bytes_read;
        int fd;
        fd = fileno(stdin);                                             /* Get file descriptor of stdin */
        nbytes = sizeof(buffer);
        bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, nbytes);                          /* Read from stdin */
        int i, n;
        char *ptr;
        char *string = argv[1];                                                 /* Arguments to string */
        n = strtol(string, &ptr, 10);                                           /* Cast string to int */
        for (i=0; i<bytes_read; i++) {
                if      (buffer[i]<=90 && buffer[i]>=65) {                      /* If UPPERCASE CHARACTERS, then */
                        shifted_buffer[i] = ((buffer[i]-65+n)%26)+65;   /* shift n places and take the remainder of 26 */
                }
                else if (buffer[i]<=122 && buffer[i]>=97) {                     /* If LOWERCASE CHARACTERS, then  */
                        shifted_buffer[i] = ((buffer[i]-97+n)%26)+97;   /* shift n places and take the remainder of 26 */
                }
                else {                                                          /* if SPECIAL CHARACTERS, then  */
                        shifted_buffer[i] = buffer[i];                  /* just copy buffer */
                }
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", shifted_buffer);                        /* Write shifted_buffer to stdout */
}
```

Testing it:

```
echo -n 'BZDRZQ’R VHED LTRS AD ZANUD RTROHBHNM' | ./Caesar 1
CAESAR’S WIFE MUST BE ABOVE SUSPICION

echo -n 'BZDRZQ’R VHED LTRS AD ZANUD RTROHBHNM' | ./Caesar 27
CAESAR’S WIFE MUST BE ABOVE SUSPICION
```

(Previously wouldn't work for 2 digits numbers)